# How to get the 2 most recent values from a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I understand that the MAX function in Access will get you the last/largest/most recent data in a table.  What I need to do is get the *two* most recent records from a table, based on an ID.

So, given this table (we'll call it tblMyData):

```
Group       SEQ       Blah1    Blah2
123         1          X1         Y1
123         2          X2         Y2
123         3          X3         Y3
123         4          X4         Y4
456         1          Q1         Z1
456         2          Q2         Z2
456         3          Q3         Z3
```

I want the resulting dataset to be:

```
Group       SEQ       Blah1    Blah2
123         3          X3         Y3
123         4          X4         Y4
456         2          Q2         Z2
456         3          Q3         Z3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather tricky.  One method is a correlated subquery and `in`:

```
select t.*
from tblMyData as t
where t.seq in (select top 2 t2.seq
                from tblMyData as t2
                where t2.group = t.group
                order by t2.seq desc
               );
```

Comment: Does the IN operator work in Access SQL?  It 's giving me an error.

Comment: @JohnnyBones . . . Yes, `in` works.  I don't think parentheses are allowed around the `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use corelated subquery to give numbers to each record per `group` and fetch two latest records per `group` in descending order of the `seq` as follows:

```
select t.* from 
       (select t.*,
               (select count(*) 
                 from tblmydata tt
                where tt.group = t.group
                  and tt.seq >= t.seq) as rn
          from tblmydata as t
        ) as t
 where t.rn <= 2;
```